Transistor withstand voltage tester
There are some cheap transistor withstand voltage testers around. Aliexpress and eBay are full of them for under $20.
I guess the principle is that the tester increases the voltage (with current limiting.)
Say it is limited to 1 mA, and increases voltage from 0 V to 2000 V. It measures the highest reached voltage.
I thought that each breakdown occurrence damages the PN junction in that transistor.
Am I wrong about this, or does current limiting simply prevent this from happening?
Is it just matter of keeping power dissipation under control?

See if you can find such testers on reputable selling sites.

Breakdown in a junction does not necessarily cause damage (though it can reportedly reduce beta in transistors if E-B breakdown is sustained at higher currents, short pulses at relatively low current don't seem to cause noticeable damage. Of course overheating can damage the part. There are test conditions specified for parts, such as 2N4401


Pulse Test: Pulse Width ≤ 300us, Duty Cycle ≤ 2.0%.

Note the pulse test conditions. 2% duty cycle maximum and maximum pulse width of 300 microseconds.
Testing MOSFET gates to gate oxide breakdown will cause permanent damage (though if there is protection internally you may not get to that voltage without substantial current flowing).
If you're just testing to see if the part can withstand the rated voltage, you can apply it and if the current flow is lower than the datasheet says, then the part conforms.
I'm not sure I see the 'use case' for such a device. I looked at one at random on Amazon and it showed poorly photoshopped connections to a car battery (??) and to electrical switchgear and electrics that one would have to be criminally insane to connect to such a device due to what is obvious about the construction and sub-standard test leads. As to use on normal electronic components, if you have unknown components around it would probably be better to dispose of them responsibly and get new ones through a reliable supply chain.
There is some small demand for things like the classic Tek575 or 576 curve tracers (available on the used market in various conditions) which can put something like 1500V on a device for testing- with proper interlocks and a fixture, but they're neither cheap nor small.

The use case for such devices is largely limited to compliance testing, R&D, and production screening, for which you'd use more sophisticated devices like a Tek 575/370A, Agilent 150x, or Tesec testers, not anything like this. A Tek 575 or other curve tracer would be much superior for didactic purposes, too, so I agree that I don't know why you'd use one of these cheap pieces of junk.

I think those testers I mentioned test collector-emitter or drain-source breakdown voltage or diode reverse voltage breakdown. Not gate-source or base-emitter.

Use case could be: when repairing faulty boards and you want to test power transistors whether they are good and are able to withstand working voltage or not.

@Chupacabras Lowered voltage withstand capability is not a typical failure mode of semiconductors. Usually transistors just fail short or are blown apart (probably by failing short first).  For insulation testing you typically want kV.

Another use case: when you buy some transistors (from not reputable source) and you want to test them whether they meet specifications. Sites like Aliexpress or ebay are full of fakes. I know it is not good idea to buy transistors from Aliexpress, I do not recommend it at all. I just mention this use case.
